# Get value of certain cell of a table with jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I get the value of a specific cell of a `table` inside a `div`?
Unfortunately I can't seem to find out how to do it by myself and googling didn't help me :-(

Example:

```
<div class="s3">
    <table id="content" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>cell 1</td>
            <td>cell 2</td>
            <td>cell 3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="s3">
    <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>cell 1</td>
            <td>cell 2</td>
            <td>cell 3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="s3">
    <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>cell 1</td>
            <td>cell 2</td>
            <td>cell 3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var count = $(".s3").length;

        for (var i = 0; i++; i < count) {
            $(".s3 div:eq(i) td:eq(0)").html("12345678");
        }
    });

</script>
```

I want to change the values of **all first cells** at once, but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if my answer solves your question please mark it as accepted. That serves both to remove the question from the "unanswered questions" category and honors the work put into writing a detailed answer. Thanks!

Comment: Dear Leon, thanks for your exhaustive answer. How I can accept it in according with your request? :-) yeah, i'm new by here.

Comment: there should be a grayed-out check mark (✓) left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: lol. done, it was not obviously frankly speaking. thanks once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why your code does not work

The way you build your selector does not work the way you expect it to. When you write `"div:eq(i)"` in JavaScript, the string will contain the actual *character* i ("div:eq(i)"), not the *current value* of the variable `i` (e.g. "div:eq(2)").

---

#### Solution 1

There are two ways to do what you want to achieve. The first variant is going the way you are in your code, but building the selector string with the variable:

```
for (var i = 0; i++; i < count) {
    $(".s3 div:eq(" + i + ") td:eq(0)").html("12345678");
}
```

This will fill in the value of the variable `i` into the selector as you intended, but will not work, since the selector `.s3 div` matches a `<div>` that is **inside** an element with `class="s3"`:

```
<div class="s3">
    <div>div you are targeting now</div>
</div>
```

To select a div that *has the class s3 itself*, you can use `div.s3` or just omit the element tag and select only using the class via `.s3`:

```
for (var i = 0; i++; i < count) {
    $("div.s3:eq(" + i + ") td:eq(0)").html("12345678");
}
```

---

#### Solution 2

With jQuery, however, you can also select *the first column of all divs* and change the text/html
of **all of them at once**, without needing to loop over them:

```
$(".s3 td:first-child").text("12345678");
```

- uses `text()` instead of `.html()` since you are inserting text, not HTML
- directly selects all `<td>`s you want to change
- uses `:first-child` (browser-supported) instead of `:eq(0)` (only jQuery-supported).

  This won't matter for this small example, but selecting using HTML-standard selectors uses the browser's native DOM engine to select elements instead of using the slower, jQuery-specific selector engine and would be a bit faster in larger real-life applications
- removes the `for` loop since jQuery can do that for you

---

Have fun learning jQuery!